# SSRS check if user in group using Custom Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, system.security

I have created a Custom Assembly for my SSRS Project.

The Custom Assembly has got 2 functions, `IsInGroup` and `MyTest`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace SSRS_Custom_Fuctions
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public static bool IsInGroup(string user, string group)
        {
            using (var identity = new WindowsIdentity(user))
            {
                var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
                return principal.IsInRole(group);
            }
        }

        public static string MyTest()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

1) The basic function `MyTest` which returns a string 'Hello World' works perfectly fine from the Report using the expression `=SSRS_Custom_Functions.Class1.MyTest()`

2) The function `IsInGroup` which returns a boolean value is not working. This is using the `System.Security.Principal` namespace to check if the username passed to the function exists in the group passed to the function. When trying to invoke it using expression `=SSRS_Custom_Functions.Class1.IsInGroup(User.User1, "MyGroupName")`, the report is bailing out with the following error message:

> request for the permission of type System.Security failed

I have modified the configuration files `rssrvpolicy.config` in the ReportingServices file path and `RSPreviewPolicy.config` in the the VisualStudio file path according to [Microsoft KB920769](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920769).

I added a `CodeGroup` which gives `FullTrust` to my custom assembly.

The following has been added to the policy level element:

```
<CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup"
           version="1"
           PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
           Name="SSRS_Custom_Fuctions"
           Description="Code group for my data processing extension">

<IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition"
                      version="1"
                      Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\SSRS_Custom_Fuctions.dll"/>
</CodeGroup>
```

I am still getting the same error message as above.

Comment: You need to check your logs, which will be at ..\Reporting Services\LogFiles, it will give you the other DLLs information which also need to added to Code Access Security group with FullTrust permission.
In this it could be System.Security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your assembly, you need to Assert the SecurityPermission object first before using it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace SSRS_Custom_Fuctions
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public static bool IsInGroup(string user, string group)
        {

        System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission sp = new System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);
        sp.Assert();

            using (var identity = new WindowsIdentity(user))
            {
                var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
                return principal.IsInRole(group);
            }
        }

        public static string MyTest()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the AssemblyInfo file you need to add `namespace System.Security` and

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()] .
```

Sign the assembly with certificate and also deploy the same in GAC of machine.

Comment: This on its own will not suffice. The solution is to Assert the SecurityPermission object.